# Queue Build Dialog - Disabled option to select Latest Source/Shelvesets

Tags: tfs

The option to select latest sources / Shelveset in the Queue Build Dialog is disabled.

Team Explorer - Builds - Queue New Build

The second dropdown on What do you want to build is disabled. I actually want to build my shelvesets instead of Latest sources.

Latest sources is the only option selected and the dropdown is disabled. How can this be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each build process template has a parameter called **SupportedReasons**. This enum is normally set to all, but you can also unselect the option **ValidateShelveset** to disable a shelveset build option, as shown in the picture below :
[image: Uncheck the ValidateShelveset illustration]

Did you change the setting here?  If not, just refresh your build definition in Team Explorer or create a new build definition with the same settings. Try it again.